# Read serial port work good in windows XP but stop working and slow in windows 7

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-7, serial-port, windows-xp

I'm talking about C# programing and communicate with serial port and different results in Windows 7 and XP.
my code is:

```
    int count = 0;
    float data1;
    float data2;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort1.PortName = textBox1.Text;
        serialPort1.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

        serialPort1.Open();
        serialPort1.Write("?");

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort1.Close();

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //string pathfile = @"C:\Documents and Settings\Dlab\Desktop\";
        //string filename = "data1.txt";
        //System.IO.File.WriteAllText(pathfile + filename, chart1.SaveImage();
       // this.chart1.SaveImage(@"C:\Documents and Settings\Dlab\Desktop\data1p.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);

        //Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(500, 500);
        //chart1.DrawToBitmap(bmp1, new Rectangle(0, 0, 500, 500));
        //bmp1.Save(@"C:\Documents and Settings\Dlab\Desktop\data1b.png");

        //chart1.Serializer.Save(@"C:\Documents and Settings\Dlab\Desktop\data1t.text");



        //this.chart2.SaveImage(@"C:\Documents and Settings\Dlab\Desktop\data2p.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);

        //Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(500, 500);
        //chart2.DrawToBitmap(bmp2, new Rectangle(0, 0, 500, 500));
        //bmp2.Save(@"C:\Documents and Settings\Dlab\Desktop\data2b.png");

        //chart2.Serializer.Save(@"C:\Documents and Settings\Dlab\Desktop\data12.text");
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        //foreach (string port in ports)
        //{
        //   comboBox1.Items.Add(port);

        // }

    }

    byte[] rs = new byte[53];


    int rscnt = 0;
   // DateTime then = DateTime.Now;
   // float dt;
    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {





        if (e.EventType != SerialData.Chars) return;
        rscnt += serialPort1.Read(rs, rscnt, 53 - rscnt);
        if (rscnt == 53)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => type(rs)));
            rs = new byte[53];
            rscnt = 0;
        }

    }
    private void type(byte[] data)
    {
        //if (rs[0] == 65)
        //{ 
       // }
        //DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        //dt = ((now.Second - then.Second));
        //label8.Text =  dt.ToString();
        //textBox3.Text = dt.ToString();


        data1 = ((rs[1] * 65536) + (rs[2] * 256) + (rs[3])-10000000)/100;
        data2 = ((rs[4] * 16777216) + (rs[5] * 65536) + (rs[6] * 256) + (rs[7])-1000000000)/2136;

        count++;
        label5.Text = count.ToString();
        label3.Text = data1.ToString();
        label4.Text = data2.ToString();

        //chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(count, data1);
        //chart2.Series[0].Points.AddXY(count, data2);

        //list1.Add(count, rs[1]);
        //zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.AddCurve("", list1, Color.Red);

        //zedGraphControl1.AxisChange();
        // zedGraphControl1.Refresh();
        serialPort1.DiscardInBuffer();



    }
    //  PointPairList list1 = new PointPairList();
}
}
```

this program work good in windows XP but when I try it in windows 7, It is slow, get wrong data and after a little stop working.

I wrote this program again in windows 7 and xp and I tested it with visual studio 2008 and 2012 but I got same results.

Comment: Are you using a built in serial port in your computer or are you using an adapter for the serial port ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'wrong data'? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: I use USB to RS 458 converter

and I don't get any error at first but after a little I get Stop working error

and wrong data means the value of data1 and data2 that I received is wrong

Comment: wrong data -> do you mean the bytes are wrong ? Propably the settings are different (check the settings like XOn XOff, etc..) you can try to receive the data via the tool "RealTerm" to check if you are able to receive correct data.

Comment: What kind of adapter are you using ? (I experienced a lot of issue using adapters)

Comment: I sure the problem isn't related to any harware thing because I got correct result in windows XP!!
and wrong data means sometimes(not always) I got wrong data I think data jumps sometimes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void type(byte[] data)
{
   ...
   serialPort1.DiscardInBuffer();
}
```

That's one heck of a nasty bug.  You are throwing away bytes in the receive buffer that should never be discarded.  The exact moment in time that you do this is highly unpredictable, it depends on when type() starts running.  Which runs on the UI thread, that timing is *very* unpredictable and is certainly affected by what OS you run this on.  That this works at all on XP is just blind luck.

Using DiscardInBuffer() is almost never correct, it should only ever be used right after calling SerialPort.Open() to purge old data from the receive buffer.  Or to recover from a protocol error, trying to re-synchronize the transmitter and receiver.  But you have no protocol, discarding bytes like this just produces garbage data with a random set of bytes missing.  Producing delays, you can only get the buffer filled with *some* bytes from the next transmission.  And crashes, whatever you do with the corrupt data is liable to fall over badly.

You **must** delete that statement.

Comment: thanks,I did this, now I don't get stop working error, but I still slow (but not same as past)..., I send data each 9ms and I can read and plot it correctly in windows XP but now I get data each 25 ms in windows 7!!....and sometimes (less than past) I have jump in my data

Comment: and another thing when I use the code in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31155232/read-22-byte-from-ftdi-serial-port-in-c-sharp-is-too-slow  I have same result with now...I don't have last problem in windows 7

Comment: Updating a chart every 9 milliseconds is quite pointless, no human can actually see that.  And it is expensive, you'll easily fire-hose the UI thread when it can't keep up.  Collect data and don't update the chart until at least 50 msec has passed.  And keep the Series small by throwing away old data.

Comment: my converter has a LED to show the data received...the strange thing it is light and after a little stop and start again and I receive in C# same thing with something LED show...it seems the C# get command micro unlike windows XP

Comment: I don't plot now I just read "count" (charts are comment)each 40 second and calcute the time...baudrate is 115200 and I read 53 byte

Comment: I had a hardware problem...now I can read and plot data each 9ms...thanks